Unir dos archivos en Pyspark
Tengo dos archivos en dos dataframes tienen los mismos tipos de datos y numero de columnas quiero sumar las filas de ambos en uno solo como lo hago
spark.sparkContext.addFile(URL_VAbr)
spark.sparkContext.addFile(URL_VAug)


df00 = spark.read.csv("file://"+SparkFiles.get("Ventas_April_2019.csv"), header =True, inferSchema=True) + spark.read.csv("file://"+SparkFiles.get("Ventas_August_2019.csv"), header =True, inferSchema=True)


Una de los "requisitos" para preguntar es hacer una investigación previa cosa que no has hecho. Realmente es más complicado preguntar aquí que buscar en Google.
